# How to use move_to_top in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to let an object go to the front with this code:

```
flap1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, move_to_top); // Add the button click

function move_to_top(e:MouseEvent):void {

movieclip1.setChildIndex(this, movieclip1.numChildren-1);

}
```

but I get Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

if the object is on the front it needs to do something like .animation in jquery things like this http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and than especially the demo with animate block 1 and block 2 this:

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block1" )
    .animate({
      width: "90%"
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
    })
```

but than in as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you code is written you're moving `this` to the top of `movieclip1`'s children. Are you sure you wanted to do this? Error is giving you a perfect reason for itself: `this` is not a child of `movieclip1`.

I think you wanted to move `movieclip1` to the top of `this`'s children. That way you should write your code like this:

```
this.setChildIndex(movieclip1, this.numChildren - 1);
```

About the animation part, I think you're reffering to tweens in Actionscript 3. I suggest using [Greensock's TweenMax Library](http://greensock.com) which is really easy to master and free to use for non-subscription and non-gambling projects.

Comment: the only thing is it has to go to the background again if I play the current animation again

Comment: btw this http://www.greensock.com/throwprops/ is what I  needed but they don't let tje object spread out so it becomes bigger do you know where I can find that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by spreading out, are you trying to make it scale? If so you can use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties. To send the `movieclip1` to the back you should call the same method, but change the second parameter so that it looks like this: `this.setChildIndex(movieclip1, 0);`

Comment: thanks I meand this: I have used the greensock code to let the object "spread out" with TweenMax but to let it go back again I get errors if I use this code: var myTween:TweenMax = new TweenMax(movieclip1, 3, {y:200, repeat:2,  repeatDelay:1, onComplete:myFunction});

movieclip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reverse); // Add the button click

function reverse(e:MouseEvent):void {

TweenMax.reverse();} in an addEventListener

Comment: You are calling `reverse()` method statically on `TweenMax` not on your tween object. Try changing `TweenMax.reverse();` with `myTween.reverse();` note that `myTween` should be declared as an instance variable if you want to access it from another method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the object you are trying to move is flap1?
And flap1 is a child of movieclip1?

In that case you need is:

```
movieclip1.setChildIndex(flap1, movieclip1.numChildren-1);
```

The error you are describing is exactly right, the DisplayObject you are referencing needs to be a child of the called. In this case, the caller is movieclip1 (because it is calling the method setChildIndex). And flap1 is a child of movieclip1.

Comment: flap1 is not the object the object is movieclip1 and it has to go to the front if you click on flap1